# Github - how to download all repository information in the json format?

Tags: api, search, github, repository

I want to explore all repository information from Github and build a database.
I have read the Github api docs, and found that the name of a specific repo or a specific query must be given when carrying out search operations.

Without a specific query, the search cannot be processed.

So is it possible to download all repo information in the json format via the API without specifying what exact repos to be searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for a large-scale query on *all* GitHub (public) repositories, you would need to use **[GitHub BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github)** instead.

With that service, you can run a query on all GitHub repo.